# Dense vector with Elasticsearch .NET

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, .net-core, vector

Using Elasticsearch.Net or NEST, what is the best way to create an index containing a dense vector?

The request via API is:

```
PUT /my-index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "text_vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 512
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i get the same result with the .net library?

---

**Update**

I solved in this way:

```
var response = client.LowLevel.Indices.Create<CreateIndexResponse>(index, PostData.Serializable(new
{
    settings = new
    {
        number_of_shards = 1,
        number_of_replicas = 1
    },
    mappings = new
    {
        properties = new
        {
            text = new
            {
                type = "text"
            },
            text_vector = new
            {
                type = "dense_vector",
                dims = 512
            }
        }
    }
}));
```